# Laravel, Eloquent n:m relationship

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent, laravel-5

I try do define a n:m relationship in Laravel using Eloquent. I have the following tables given:

users:

- ID
- foo

things

- ID

users_things

- thing_id
- foo

In my `User` Model I have defined the following relation

```
public function things() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Thing', 'user_things', 'foo', 'thing_id');
}
```

In the `Things` Model is the counterpart

```
public function users() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'user_things', 'thing_id', 'foo');
}
```

When I call in the Controller

```
$user = User::find(1) //works
//$thing = Thing::find(1) works
$things = $user->things();
return $things
```

I get the following message:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could
> not be converted to string.

My problem is that, I cannot use the User `ID` as foreign key in the combination table. It has to be the `foo` column.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to have anything to do with relations. Somewhere in your code an object is converted to a string. Have a look at the error message, there should be filename and line number where the error occurs. Please paste that part of the code.

Comment: What happens when you `return dd($things)? `$user->things()` returns an instance of Collection. Use dynamic attribute instead and see if works: `$things = $user->things;` or `$things = $user->things->first();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this (Use `belongsToMany` for `many-to-many` relationship):

```
// User.php

protected $primaryKey = 'foo';
public $incrementing = false;

public function things() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Thing', 'user_things', 'foo', 'thing_id');
}

// Thing.php
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_things', 'thing_id', 'foo');
}
```

Finally, use `$user->things` instead of `$user->things()`.